# glossaries-extra's toc option out of control!

Tags: table-of-contents, acronyms, glossaries-extra

I've established a list of abbreviations and a glossary using the `glossaries-extra` package. I noticed that the abbreviations and glossary are always part of the table of contents, no matter whether I set `toc=true`or `toc=false`. I dont't want them there, or at least not the abbreviations section. The [glossaries-extra documentation](https://mirror.dogado.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.pdf) was no help here, and I haven't found this problem through googling yet (though my google skills aren't the best so I might have missed something). I've tried this with different latex programs (tex maker and overleaf), same result. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage[
    toc=false,%aparently same result as toc=true
    sort=none,
    section,
    numberedsection=autolabel,
    abbreviations,
    nogroupskip
    ]{glossaries-extra}
    
    

%%Abbreviations
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}%

\newabbreviation{apa}{APA}{American Psychological Association}
\newabbreviation{ex}{EX}{An Example}    
%%


%%Glossary entries
\newglossaryentry{glossary}
{
    name=Glossary,
    description={A collection of words with explanations}
}

\newglossaryentry{psych}
{
    name=Psychology,
    description={The scientific study of mind and behavior}
}
%%


\title{A title}

    
    
\begin{document}
\maketitle

    \tableofcontents
    
    
    \clearpage
    
    \printunsrtglossary[type=abbreviations]%List of Abbreviations
    
    \clearpage
    
    
    \section{Heading 1}
    
    blabla
    
    \section{Heading 2}
    
    blibli
    

    \appendix
    \printunsrtglossary[title=A Glossary]%Main Glossary
        
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think that you are doing anything wrong. The code seems not to honor the setting for \printunsrtglossary. `\renewcommand\glossarysection[2][]{\section*{#1}}` should work, but make also bug report.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The `\renewcommand` worked perfectly. Will do the bug report!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an interaction with the `numberedsection` option. When this selects a numbered section, it uses the `\section` command directly and bypasses the code that checks for the `toc` option. And `\section` always adds to the table of contents. So removing `numberedsection` or setting it to false solves it, and then it uses `\section*` plus the check for the `toc` option. This gives the same output as Ulrikes `\renewcommand`.